# Determining $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ when $f(a)=f(b)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to integrate $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ when $f(a)=f(b)$

Can something like $\int_0^kf(x)dx=2\int_0^{k\over2}f(x)dx$ for $f(x)=f(k-x)$ be somehow used?

Comment: You just proceed in the usual way: Find an antiderivative $F$ of $f$, and evaluate at the endpoints before subtracting.

Answer (score 2):

Even if $f(a)=f(b)$ there is no difference than usual way of integrating. Try to get antiderivative.

And $\int_0^k f(x)dx = 2\int _0^{k/2}f(x)dx$ can be only used if $f(x)=f(k-x)$ for all $x$. Since it is symmetric to $k/2$, $\int_0^{k/2}f(x)dx$ is equal to $\int _{k/2}^{k}f(x)dx$. So following is true. $$\int_0^k f(x)dx = \int_0^{k/2}f(x)dx +\int _{k/2}^{k}f(x)dx = 2\int _0^{k/2}f(x)dx$$

Comment: I know about this $\int_0^k f(x)dx = 2\int _0^{k/2}f(x)dx$ can be only used if $f(x)=f(k-x)$ for all $x$. Since it is symmetric to $k/2$, $\int_0^{k/2}f(x)dx$ is equal to $\int _{k/2}^{k}f(x)dx$. So following is true. $$\int_0^k f(x)dx = \int_0^{k/2}f(x)dx +\int _{k/2}^{k}f(x)dx = 2\int _0^{k/2}f(x)dx$$

But how to get the value of the definite integral when f(a)=f(b), since putting the limits evaluates 0 as the answer?
If it can done by using the concept of symmetry, then how to find out the points where the integral is symmetric?

Comment: Now I understood the question.

If given condition is only $f(a)=f(b)$ I don't think there isn't such technique as $\int_0^kf(x)dx=2\int_0^{k/2}f(x)dx$. 

Only with $f(a)=f(b)$ you can't know anything about antiderivative of $f(x)$.